# Excel part II: Take nth value within a sub set

Tags: excel-formula

Let me make a second part to another stupid question I can't sort. Imagine we have a list like

```
Week Value Accept? First
1 a TRUE a
1 b TRUE
1 c FALSE
2 d FALSE
2 e FALSE
2 f TRUE f
3 g FALSE
3 h FALSE
3 i FALSE
4 j FALSE
4 k TRUE k
4 l TRUE
```

How do I make a formula that outputs the first value **within a subset** with satisfies a condition. 
In rows 2 to 4, it would be B2
In rows 5 to 7, it's B6
In rows 8 to 10 there is no answer: all false.
In rows 11 to 13, it will be B12, ignoring B13 which also is true.
I will appreciate any recommendation, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your titles starts in A1

Write in D2 :
    {=IF(A1<>A2,INDEX($B$1:$B$100,MATCH(A2&TRUE,$A$1:$A$100&$C$1:$C$100,0))}

the {} shall be inserted by pressing ctrl+shift+enter ([array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d))

then extend this formula all the way down. It should give you what you want.

What it does :

```
IF(A1<>A2,
```

will only display the result if the cell in the lefthand column is a new week number

```
INDEX($B$1:$B$100,
```

will return the n-th value of the column B, where n is :

```
MATCH(A2&TRUE,$A$1:$A$100&$C$1:$C$100,0)
```

will return the first line for which the columns A and C concatenated has for value A2&TRUE. It is the reason why you need to use array formula